# can we call a cmd script from zend controller action?

Tags: php, command-line, zend-framework2

My idea is to write some script ( cmd / unix ) and call it from within my action. I did a search in google but I didn't found anything. The idea is to create a script (example: I want to call this script: **cp file public/uploads** ).

This is my action :

```
public function editAction()
{
    //here i want to call my script
    $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
    $article = $this->getObjectManager()->find('\Application\Entity\Article', $id);

    if ($this->zfcUserAuthentication()->hasIdentity()) 
    {
        if ($this->request->isPost()) 
        {

            $article->setTitle($this->getRequest()->getPost('title'));
            $article->setDate(new \DateTime($this->getRequest()->getPost('date')));
            $article->setContent($this->getRequest()->getPost('content'));
            $article->setPublication($this->getRequest()->getPost('publication'));

            $article->getImage($id)->setUrl($this->getRequest()->getPost('path'));
            $article->getImage($id)->setAlt($this->getRequest()->getPost('alt'));

            $this->getObjectManager()->persist($article);
            $this->getObjectManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('blog');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('user');
    }
    return new ViewModel(array('article' => $article));
}
```

So if someone has any ideas about that, I will be very appreciative :)

Comment: What do you mean by "cmd script"? If you talk about console applications, yes, that works. See information for the [`Zend\Console`-Component](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.console.introduction.html)

Comment: You mean using exec? http://www.php.net/function.exec